# Visit site with Cron Job on another domain

Tags: php, cron

So we've got an ever growing list of domains that need a daily cron job to reach a page on it.

Currently, I have a script on DomainA and the cron job is set up on DomainA.

The script looks like this:

```
<?php
$site_array = array(
    'http://demo.DomainA.com/',
    'http://demo.DomainB.com/',
        ...
);

foreach( $site_array as $site ){
    ob_start();
    file_get_contents( $site.'page-to-visit' );
    $temp = ob_get_clean();
    ob_end_clean();
}

?>
```

This script creates an array of all the domains, and then uses `file_get_contents()` to visit the page. The only problem is, each domains `/page-to-visit` page has some PHP on it to do things inside the site.

It seems to run DomainA's (the site the Cron/Script is on) `page-to-visit` script just fine, but DomainB's seems unaffected. Is `file_get_contents` the wrong function to use? I've considered using `include`, but that doesn't work cross-site/domain.

And it's not really feasible to create a Cron on each domain, as they get added all the time. I'd like that to be an absolute last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `file_get_contents()` should work try to use curl instead

```
<?php
 $site_array = array(
     'http://demo.DomainA.com/',
     'http://demo.DomainB.com/',
        ...
 );

 foreach( $site_array as $site ){
     ob_start();
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site.'page-to-visit');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 15);
     $data = curl_exec($ch);
     echo $site . ' : ' . curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';
     curl_close($ch);
     ob_end_clean();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is enabled to make a http request? You should check the return value.

If it doesn't return `false`, all php will have been executed except when there are ajax requests as javascript will not run.

If it does return `false` you could use cURL instead. Note that the same applies to javascript / ajax.

Comment: How do I enable it to make an HTTP request? Is that the whole `stream_context_create()` thing?

Comment: @Xhynk See the note at the end in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php and http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen. Does `file_get_contents()` return `false`?